# How to retrive data's from model list based on index postion and store in textview

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Im new to Firebase

I am trying to retrieve some specific data from a Firebase. I have a node universities and that node has many unique identifier as node which has so more data into it. I want to retrieve name from each node.

[image: Please have a loot at this.]

And i want to store that all name's into a list using OnChildEventListener()...

```
List<University> universityList = new ArrayList<>();myRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("universities").child(userid);
myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() { 
    @Override public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { 
        University university = dataSnapshot.getValue(University.class); 
        universityList.add(university); 
        Log.i(TAG,"add university name = " + university.name); 
    } 
}
```

By this above code i can able to store that all names from firebase to list.

Now I want to get that name's from the list based on index position and store it in textview. This was my problem.

Comment: Please post referenece you provided so we can help properly

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make simple Adapter and just pass the list you received in it.

And access element position in `onBindViewHolder()`

then you can set your `TextView`

```
public class UniversityAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UniversityAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<University> universityList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public name;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
    }


    public MoviesAdapter(List<University> universityList) {
        this.universityList = universityList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.university_list_item, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        University university = universityList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(university.getName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return universityList.size();
    }
}
```